# Protractor element all filter broken

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, protractor

I have the following function:

```
var getUserInList = function(email){
console.log('getUserInList email:'+email);
element.all(by.repeater('user in users')).filter(function(el, index){
    console.log('index:'+index);
    return el.element(by.binding('user.email')).getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('text:'+text+' email:'+email);
        return text === email;
    });
  }).then(function(els){
    console.log('els length'+els.length+'els[0]'+els[0]);
    if(els.length === 0)return null;
    return els[0];
  });
};
```

On the first call it gives the following output to the console:

```
.getUserInList email:test2@test.com
end create
index:0
index:1
index:2
text:test2@test.com email:test2@test.com
text:test@test.com email:test2@test.com
text:rory.gilfillan@gmail.com email:test2@test.com
els length1els[0][object Object]
index:0
index:1
index:2
text:test2@test.com email:test2@test.com
text:test@test.com email:test2@test.com
text:rory.gilfillan@gmail.com email:test2@test.com
index:0
index:1
index:2
text:test2@test.com email:test2@test.com
text:test@test.com email:test2@test.com
text:rory.gilfillan@gmail.com email:test2@test.com
.start delete
getUserInList email:test3@test.com
```

Amazingly although the function supposedly returns a value in line 9 in the console, the function continues to run. Then when the function is called again, it simply return undefined, no promise is returned. The first console output of the function is there but nothing after that. This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element.all(by.repeater('user in users')).filter(function(el, index){
```

should be

```
return element.all(by.repeater('user in users')).filter(function(el, index){
```

Comment: Link to documentation - http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter